# My "great" ubuntu 14.04 LTS totaly crashed after tlp instalation

Tags: 14.04, wireless, apt, crash

My Dell Inspiron worked like vacuum cleaner with ubuntu 14. Not far I found solution on this forum about tlp power manager that could resolve my problem. But after I tried to use this awesome advise I've got new problem my apt-get just stoped work

```
➜  ~  sudo apt-get install 4digits
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
4digits : Depends: python-glade2 but it is not going to be installed
linux-tools-3.13.0-53 : Depends: linux-tools-common but it is not going to be     installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

I tried to do "apt-get -f install" but it wont work

```
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-common_3.13.0-53.89_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-common (3.13.0-53.89) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-  common_3.13.0-53.89_all.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/perf', which is also in package linux-   lts- vivid-tools-common 3.19.0-18.18~14.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_3.13.0-53.89_all.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

After I found a new decision on that forum, they said I just need make

```
dpkg -r --force-update lts-vivid-tools-common
```

and after reboot I dont have WiFi and sound anymore. Have I chance restore my installation or that "great" distro might be fix only with reinstallation every time?

Comment: manually remove dependent packages `linux-tools-3.13.0-53` `python-glade2` with `apt-get remove --purge` and then install `4digits` and `linux-tools-3.13.0-53` `python-glade2` if you not succeed you probably using duplicated sources/ppa look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies) to get more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after installing TLP. I solved it by looking for linux-tools-3.13.0-53 in Synaptic and installing it through Synaptic.

Answer (score -1):

You just might need to update the drivers. Go to Dell's website and find the make and model of video and sound card and try to find a driver either;

1. Find a driver manually online
   or
2. Install the driver through Ubuntu

And, for now, use Ethernet, I guess